# How to display data in store in redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I just started with reacts/redux and trying to get my head around store/state. I built a component which successfully receives data and then passes this into the reducer. This is my component:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react');
var PropTypes = React.PropTypes;

import axios from 'axios';
import store from '../../store';
import {getDataSuccess, getDataFail} from '../../actions/userData-actions'
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class ServiceDetails extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            tabs: null,
            tabContent: null
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:3001/0')
            .then(response => {
                console.log('getservicedetails=response.data', response.data);
                store.dispatch(getDataSuccess(response.data));
                return response;
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                store.dispatch(getDataFail(error));
            });

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <section className="ServiceDetails">
                <h1>id:{props.userData.users[0].id}</h1>
                service details new
            </section>
        )
    }
}


const mapStateToProps = function (store) {
    console.log('Servicedetails mapStatetoprops =',store );
    return {
        data: store.datas,
        userData: store.apiData
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ServiceDetails);
```

The mapstatetoProps function receives the data but how can I render this data? How can I display the data from the store?

Comment: That looks about right. Just that, you need to ensure that application is wrapped by `react-redux`'s [`Provider` component](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#vanilla-react).

Answer (score 1):

I could not see reducer in your code. Also your function this

```
const mapStateToProps = function (store) {
  return {
    data: store.data,
    userData: store.apiData
  };
};
```

will map new state to props, & that will re-render your component. As a result
your component will be updated with new/updated data.

Also please verify and fix if possible these stuff:

- You should use this.props.userData not props.userData in your render function.
- Using of Provider, so that store is used across all components.

One more thing, typo [ " datas " ]  in your mapStateToProps function.
single unit of data is called datum & more than one datum is called data not datas.

Answer (score 0):

I found it , I am checking whether the array length is larger than 0 before rendering it.